# How to enable android backup agent only on WiFi?

Tags: android, wifi

I've written a BackupAgent to backup my data, but I want to enable the backup only when WiFi is connected and not GPRS/3G/4G. Can I control that programmatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wifi State can always be known as follows :

1) Get a WifiManager object using the method  Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)

2) Use the 
[isWifiEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#isWifiEnabled%28%29) class to know the state of Wifi.

To know the status of Data Connectivity of Cellphone, get an Instance using
TelephonyManager tm = Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE), and then use

tm.[getDataState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDataState%28%29) to know the status of data connectivity.

Now, run your BackupAgent when the return value of getDataState is TelephonyManager.DATA_DISCONNECTED and the return value of isWifiEnabled is true.

To be able to disable the backup once the connection (3G/WiFi) is dropped , create a new method is follows :

```
enter code here  
protected void checkMyConnectivity()


{

if (tm.getDataState ==  TelephonyManager.DATA_DISCONNECTED && wm.isWifiEnabled==true)

return true;

else

return false;

}`
```

And use this code whenever you want to check the connectivity and if the return value is false, stop the upload. If you want to be very specific, use a while loop instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how can I stop the backup system calling my BackupAgent's onBackup()? If I just do nothing in onBackup() when wifi is not connected, then will I lose any backup?

Comment: @user868748 for that post the intended code. or best ask another question and post the link here. As far as your current question is concerned, tell me does this answer your question ??

Comment: Yes, you've just answered part of my question. The important part of the question is how to "disable" or "stop" the backup service to call upon my BackupAgent's onBackup().

Answer (score 1):

1. whenever you don't have wifi that is use the Wifi service and if no wifi then un-sync the account from the phone settings programmatically

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
Log.i(TAG,"Accounts size "+accounts.length);`for(Account acc:accounts){
    Log.d(TAG,"acc name "+acc.name+" acc type "+acc.type);
    boolean isSync = ContentResolver.isSyncActive(acc, ContactsContract.Settings.CONTENT_URI.toString());
    Log.d(TAG,"isSync "+isSync);
    cr.setSyncAutomatically(acc, , false);// here you are unsyncing the mail account
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected boolean isWifiConnectivity() {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    return (telephonyManager.getDataState() == TelephonyManager.DATA_DISCONNECTED && wifiManager.isWifiEnabled());
}
```